# Storing arrays in Django Models (not PostGreSQL)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, django, web, django-models

I want a field in my Django model to store array data.

For instance consider a model that stores Student data. I want an array field that stores the marks of that student as an integer array. What can I do?

I am **not** using PostGreSQL so I cannot use ArrayField.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    marks = models.?
```

Comment: Typically you don't. Even for PostgreSQL not the best way. Usually you make a model `Mark`, with a `ForeignKey` to `Student`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you don't. Even for PostgreSQL not advisable. Relational databases are usually better to work with *scalar* values in columns.

You can make a model `Mark`, with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to `Student`, for example:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    # …

class Mark(models.Model):
    mark = models.IntegerField()
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        related_name='marks'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

You can then create for example marks for a student:

```
student = Student.objects.create()
Mark.objects.create(student=stud, mark=7)
Mark.objects.create(student=stud, mark=8)
```

Then you access the `Mark` objects of the `student` with:

```
student.marks.all()
```

Comment: Alternatively, we can also use the `jsonfield` python library. We can do the following,

`from jsonfield import JSONField

class Student(models.Model):

    ...
 
    ...
 
    data = JSONField(default = list)
`

More can be found out at (https://pypi.org/project/jsonfield/)

Comment: @Adhishwar: I would advise not to do this. A JsonField is behind the curtains just a `CharField` with transparent wrapping between the string/data. As a result the database does not know what it stores. You thus can not order `Student`s by average grade for example with a database query.